# Oracle client installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, oracle

I installed Oracle 11g database on Windows XP(32-bit) and now I need help for installing Oracle client on Windows 7 (64-bit)

If possible, can you explain me how to do this... step by step... starting with what software I need.

Br, Wolfy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple - just install the Win-64 instant client software from Oracle's [instant client downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) - you will need to register with OTN if you haven't done so already. You can set up an ODBC DSN to test it with.

Comment: I downloaded instantclient-basic-win-x86-64-11.2.0.1.0... extracted... and now... which file I must run to install this? there is no setup or install.exe

Comment: You don't need to run anything apart from odbc_install.exe in the folder you extracted everything too - this sets up the registry entries. You'll also need to add your folder to the windows path.

Comment: In case the Instant Client is not sufficient for your requirements, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100